# What is a common term for interpolation and extrapolation

Tags: word-request

When working with empirical measurements, one often needs to render additional data based on the approximation from the provided by the observation. In the professional terms it is referred to as *interpolation* and *extrapolation*. The former meaning that we actually *fill in the gaps* whereas the latter implies *extending the edges*.

It's been increasingly painful to write both (and in most cases we do both), so I wonder if there's a smooth way to express both in one shot. I can think of **rephrasing** or **describing** the action but I'm looking for a correct term meaning *interpolation and/or extrapolation (of data)*.

Comment: Why do you think that is increasingly painful to write both? In fact, I cannot understand that part of the question.

Comment: @Cardinal Not sure if I understand your question. It **is** increasingly painful because feel it is. That's my experience of those terms. Of course, it's purely subjective and there might be entire nations consisting of individuals who get ecstatic at the joy of typing in those terms (kudos to them). However, as far my willingness to write unnecessarily many characters stretches, is awfully limited (current comment being an amusing exception).

Comment: @Cardinal My joke above aside, it's about linguistic efficiency. C.f. *the elevator is going up and down* versus *the elevator goes **vertically***.

Comment: I understand. You are looking for a way to _polate!_

Comment: @P.E.Dant Yes! Although *polate* seems not to be an actual word, as far I understand. So I'm looking for polation equivalent.

Comment: As a person who knows a little bit about the digital signal processing, I have never seen a paper whose author suffered when using those terms.

Comment: nope, as far as I know from math, science, and, like Cardinal, digital signal processing, there's really no other options because the two words actually say exactly what is intended.  Is it painful to *type* repeatedly, or painful because of its Latinish-sounding *jargon* ?  If the former - try setting up a hotkey ;-P ... if the latter, oh well, we're stuck with it.

Comment: _Interpolate_ originated in Latin _interpolare_ which itself originated in _inter_ (between) and _polare_ (cf. _polire,_ to buff or smooth.) You might get away with coining **to polate** in English, and if you convince enough readers that it's useful and admits of a precise definition (which I can't think of, myself) then you will have done a service to fatigued writers everywhere.

Comment: @Cardinal It's a bit out of the scope of my question, but in my case, I know a lot (and I say **a lot**) of people in the field of statistics, image analysis and pattern recognition that would disagree with you. And as I pointed out above - it's about linguistic proficiency and improving the mastery of English, so it's not really relevant whether most of the writers don't bother and are satisfied with the *interpolation and/or extrapolation* term. In practice, I'm willing to admit that it maybe doesn't really matter - just as you say.

Comment: @Cardinal was being jocular there, I think...

Comment: @HowardPautz It's the lengthiness of the expression that bothers me. Not the actual typing but rather the oh-my-god-so-long-sequence-of-produced-characters. It seemed interesting to inquire whether there was a more compact term for both, since they are often used in that exact composition (at least in my experience from work). I believe that I'll be going for P.E. Dant's suggestion and and start promoting *polation*, hehe.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm sure he was. In fact, so was I. He's got a very valid point (in practical terms) but we also should appreciate the beauty of the linguistic excellence (even if it won't be generally understood by the common man). Also, you might want your explanation about *polare* and *polation* as a reply so I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: LOL - the common language root of English and Swedish are (Northern) Germanic. Looks to me that typing "verksamhetsnära" might be as annoying as Inter/Extra-polation ... (ps I love German, but it, like English can get tedious too.)   ... so If you have to interpolate between two skunks (also know as Polecats), you'd have to Interpolecatpolate. (ouch)

Comment: @Cardinal So if anyone knows how to _polate,_ it is you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The English word *interpolate* was first seen between 1605 and 1615, and is based on the past participle of the Latin *interpolāre,* with the meaning *to make new, refurbish, touch up.*

The Latin *Interpolare* itself originated in *inter-* (between) and *polare,* which is related to *polire,* with the meaning *to buff or smooth.* (Our English verb and noun *polish* has its origin there, as well.)

*Extrapolate* is the verb form of the noun *Extrapolation,* which was created by analogy with *Interpolation.*  The prefix *inter* (between) was replaced with the prefix *extra* (outside (of) or without.) The first known use of *Extrapolation* was in 1874, and it was apparently coined specifically as a methematical term with the meaning "an inserting of intermediate terms in a mathematical series." Its more general use with the sense of "drawing of a conclusion about the future based on present tendencies" came later.

It is perhaps logical then to deduce:

> If we can *interpolate* and *extrapolate,* these two verbs must describe vectors of an action called *polation!*

Unfortunately, no lexicographer agrees with that deduction. However, it is heartening to remember that *extrapolation* itself was coined intentionally to satisfy a need for the term. Nothing thus prevents us from coining the verb **to polate** and its attendant form **polation.**

We might define **to polate** (provisionally and with the understanding that more work is needed) as "*to alter interstices.*"

You might get away with coining *to polate* in English, if you can formulate a useful and precise definition and convince enough readers that the new verb fulfills a need. We should not misunderestimate the capacity of English to adopt new words. In this enterprise, you can be encouraged by the history of such other recent coinages as [*audiophile,*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/audiophile?s=t) [*locavore,*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/locavore?s=t) and even [*refudiate,*](https://youtu.be/-pXaK30qNBM) which was named as Oxford Dictionary's ["Word of the Year"](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/sarah-palins-refudiate-named-word-of-the-year/) in 2010.

Comment: ***Refudiate?*** Surely that is a transitive verb meaning Elmer Fud is creating offspring?

Comment: The truth is worse.

Comment: oh, right, DUH! It means "Wee - weed'ed up."  LOL

Comment: If I tell my wife I spent the day polating, she'll make me find a new profession.